# Does Bibtex not work for CleanThesis?

Tags: bibtex, cleanthesis

I downloaded the [cleanthesis template](http://cleanthesis.der-ric.de/) and run LaTeX on `thesis-example.tex` which created an `.aux` file. In the document one finds

```
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[nottype=online]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={Webseiten},type=online,prefixnumbers={@}]
```

such that BibTeX should generate a `.bbl` file. But if I run `bibtex`, it just says

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2012)
The top-level auxiliary file: thesis-example.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file thesis-example.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file thesis-example.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file thesis-example.aux
(There were 3 error messages)
```

and just leaves an empty `.bbl` file for me. I checked `cleanthesis.sty` and found

```
\bibliography{bib-refs}
```

which is infact the correct `.bib` file.

I then deleded the command `\nocite{*}` and put some where in the text `\cite{WEB:GNU:GPL:2010}` after compiling with LaTeX I could find in the `.aux` file the command

```
\abx@aux@cite{WEB:GNU:GPL:2010}
```

but if I run `bibtex` I get the same message from above and an empty `bbl` file.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: It's using biblatex so I think current versions will default to biber rather than bibtex, although you can probably use a backend=bibtex key to force it to use bibtex compatible aux file.

Comment: see this line (commented out) in github version \RequirePackage[ % use biblatex for bibliography
% backend=biber, % - use biber backend (bibtex replacement)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do *not* want to run `biber` write *before*  you load the package `cleanthesis`:

```
 \usepackage[                   % use biblatex for bibliography
    backend=bibtex8,                    %   - use bibtex8 backend 
    bibencoding=utf8,               %   - use auto file encode
    style=alphabetic,               %   - use alphabetic (or numeric) bib style
    natbib=true,                    %   - allow natbib commands
    hyperref=true,                  %   - activate hyperref support
    backref=true,                   %   - activate backrefs
    isbn=false,                     %   - don't show isbn tags
    url=false,                      %   - don't show url tags
    doi=false,                      %   - don't show doi tags
    urldate=long,                   %   - display type for dates
    maxnames=3,%
    minnames=1,%
    maxbibnames=5,%
    minbibnames=3,%
    maxcitenames=2,%
    mincitenames=1%
]{biblatex}
```

However, at least use `bibtex8` if you have the encoding `utf8`

Comment: Thank you! I enabled `backend=bibtex`. If I use now `pdflatex thesis-example.tex` and then `bibtex8 thesis-example.aux` my .bbl file is still empty. Bibtex8 tells me again that he found no \citation,\bibdata nor \bibstyle.

Comment: I tested it with the thesis-example and bibtex and had no problem.

Comment: Did you mean in your post I should change the backend=bibtex line on line 285 in cleanthesis? This is what I did, but I just saw that you said "write before you load the package cleanthesis..". I cant put in before I load cleanthesis, because I cant load the package twice.

Comment: @Adam `bibtex` and `bibtex8` are two separate programs, if you want to use the latter with `biblatex`, specify `backend=bibtex8`.

Comment: @Adam: either my solution _or_ the one from torbjorn-t

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: it makes no difference when using `backend=bibtex` and running `bibtex8`. However, you are right that both should be the same, backend and the used program.

Comment: @Herbert Ah, ok. I'm not at all familiar with `bibtex8` so I thought perhaps there was some difference with `bibtex` causing it not to work. Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 5):

You should run `biber`, not `bibtex`, as the package uses the `biblatex` package to handle references. Newer versions of `biblatex` assume `biber` as the default backend (i.e., the program that does the sorting of the entries), so it won't work with `bibtex`.

To force `biblatex` to use `bibtex` or `bibtex8` instead, you can edit `cleanthesis.sty`. Line 285 of the current version reads

```
%   backend=biber,  [...]
```

Change this to

```
backend=bibtex,
```

or

```
backend=bibtex8,
```

For some info about `bibtex` vs. `biber` see [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701)

Comment: the package sets _no_ backend (in my version), but with current `biblatex` the default is `biber`

Comment: @Herbert Yes, you are correct. I'll rephrase my answer.